# Regex removing - unless preceded by another operator

Tags: javascript, regex

This is JS (and therefore no look behind). I would like to remove a negative sign unless it is touching another operator. However, I still want the other operator removed.

Example:

```
14/-5*6-3
```

I want the `/`,`*`, and last `-` removed, but the negative left on the 5. I'm guessing it needs to be using a look forward on `/*-+`, but that's as far as I can get without knowing how to leave the `-` behind after removing whatever operator precedes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using capturing group:

```
'14/-5*6-3'.replace(/(^|\d)[-+*\/]/g, '$1')
// => "14-563"
```

Comment: I actually came up with the solution after looking through something old I had done that was similar, but your answer matches my purpose, so I'll select it.